# Java nio2: map Path objects between filesystems without relying on toString

Tags: java, zip, nio2

I am creating a zip file from the contents of a source directory using NIO2. I am using a [ZipFileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html), for which I first have to gain an instance, and then generate paths. The generated paths can then be used to create entries in the zip file using `Files.createDirectory(pathInZip)` or `Files.copy(sourcePath, destPathInZip)`. This works fine, but there is a moment of uglyness that I would like to avoid:

```
 // within the SimpleFileVisitor that walks through sourceDirFile
 @Override
 public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    Path pathInZip = zipFileSystem.getPath(sourceDirPath.relativize(file).toString()); // <-- ?!
    Files.copy(file, pathInZip);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
 }
```

Is there a way to copy a Path from one FileSystemProvider into a Path from another without relying on `aPath.toString()`?. It seems ugly. I could always iterate over one path, incrementally building the other... but it would seem so easy to have a FileSystem.getPath(Path anotherPath) that I took the time to write this post.

Comment: apparently they didn't think of it as a common operation to map paths between file systems.

Comment: seems like an oversight; will head over to their sample zip implementation to see how they deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written some utility methods for this. Maybe you find them useful (the library is Open Source).

Tutorial: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

Javadoc: http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/index.html

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.2</version>   
</dependency>
```

More info: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/2012/07/news-from-software-smithy-version-02.html

Comment: Finally came around to revisiting answers. Nice library!.

Answer (score 1):

i have been using below dirutils lib that i think does what u are trying to do. it uses toPath.resolve()

https://github.com/bbejeck/Java-7/blob/master/src/main/java/bbejeck/nio/files/visitor/CopyDirVisitor.java

Edit:
lol now that you say it I revisited my code and noticed I had patched just that part of the lib. One forgets things so easily..

```
 @Override
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

    Path relativizedPath =fromPath.relativize(dir);

    Path targetPath = toPath.resolve(relativizedPath.toString());
    if(!Files.exists(targetPath)){
        Files.createDirectory(targetPath);
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
```

Comment: Nice code - but it does not work cross-filesystem. It seems that paths are linked to the filesystems they originate from...